# Ant nested condition

Tags: build, ant

I have an ant `build.xml` file which contains the following snippet:

```
<condition property="apiUrl" value="apiUrl1">
  <and>
    <equals arg1="${area}" arg2="area1"/>
    <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="stage"/>
  </and>
</condition>
<condition property="apiUrl" value="apiUrl2">
  <and>
    <equals arg1="${area}" arg2="area1"/>
    <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="develop"/>
  </and>
</condition>
```

As you can see from above, `<equals arg1="${area}" arg2="area1"/>` is checked twice, and the logic of the snippet is equivalent to the pseudo code:

```
if (${area} == 'area1' and ${env} == 'stage') {
  apiUrl = 'apiUrl1'
}
if (${area} == 'area1' and ${env} == 'develop') {
  apiUrl = 'apiUrl2'
}
```

How can I change `build.xml` so that its logic becomes the following nested condition?

```
if (${area} == 'area1') {
  if (${env} == 'stage') {
    apiUrl = 'apiUrl1'
  }
  if (${env} == 'develop') {
    apiUrl = 'apiUrl2'
  }      
}
```

My ant version is `1.10.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that using `script` instead of `condition` task like this:

```
<project default="init" name="My Project">

    <property name="area" value="area1" />
    <property name="env" value="develop" />

    <target name="init">
        <script language="javascript"> 
            if (project.getProperty('area') == 'area1') {
                if (project.getProperty('env') == 'stage') {
                    project.setProperty('apiUrl', 'apiUrl1');
                }
                if (project.getProperty('env') == 'develop') {
                    project.setProperty('apiUrl', 'apiUrl2');
                }      
            }
        </script>
        <echo>${apiUrl}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this seemingly minor change can seem so awkward in Ant is because while the conditional setting of properties is simply controlled with the `condition` task, the conditional flow of logic is controlled at the `target` level. Thus, if you want certain steps to run or be skipped depending on a condition, you'll have to create a separate target that first checks the condition and then tells your main target whether or not it should run.

```
<target name="setApiUrl" depends="checkArea" if="isArea1">
    <condition property="apiUrl" value="apiUrl1">
        <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="stage"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="apiUrl" value="apiUrl2">
        <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="develop"/>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="checkArea">
    <condition property="isArea1">
        <equals arg1="${area}" arg2="area1"/>
    </condition>
</target>
```